# Aptana studio selecting remote server for upload

Tags: deployment, aptana

I'm running Aptana Studio 3 and I have multiple remote connections setup for uploading my website to.
Some are for deployment, others are for testing and development.

Currently I'm have to manually drag the files across to the correct server, what I'd like to be able to do it right click on a file in the app explorer and select publish >> upload and it will go to the correct remote server, is there some way I can choose a default upload server so I can get this behaviour?

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (file, upload) will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default connection under Project > Properties > File Transfer

There will be a drop down list of all of the connections you have set up for this project, pick the one you want to use by default and check the 'Use the connection as default' box and it will not ask you where you want to upload each time. Or, you can uncheck that box and it will prompt you to choose a connection each time you upload, with the one you've selected from this screen selected.

FWIW, Ctrl + Shift + U is the default upload shortcut and way easier than find file in explorer > right click > publish > upload, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the information about setting the default, that was what I was after.